# How to use alias of interface with real ip for virtual machine in KVM

Tags: linux, virtualization, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge

Network `192.168.110.0/24` is not real. I wrote this network on `serverfault` for example.
Hello. I have interface `enp1s0` with main IP `192.168.110.180`. Part of config:

```
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet static
        address 192.168.110.180
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.110.220
```

It is ok. I created alias, with additional ip, that ISP gave me

```
auto enp1s0:1
iface enp1s0:1 inet static
        address 192.168.110.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

It works. I can ping `192.168.110.1` from internet. Everything is ok. But i want to use this IP in my virtual machine in KVM. When i had VLANS, i just created bridges, but with aliases, i don't know, what i should do. Can you help me ? How to create bridge from alias on virtual machine ?

Comment: which datacenter your server belongs to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bridge aliases. If all you have from the ISP is a single public IP your best option is to build a NAT network and pass ports through to the VMs.

Comment: but if i have several additional ip addresses ? what the best way ?

Comment: All in the same subnet?

Comment: right. maybe use proxy_arp, that i am using for lxd ?

Comment: If You have an ipv4 range you can use a bridge with the host taking up 1 ip and the vms getting the others